# What is wrong with the code below

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetPayCodeList
(     
     -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @PC varchar(50)
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(     IF @PC = '*'
       SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description
                            FROM   tbl
      ELSE
             SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description
                            FROM   tbl
          WHERE Code = @PC
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are any of those columns character and DISTINCT?

As a side note, you could rewrite it as this to make it simpler:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE @PC = '*' OR Code = @PC
```

Comment: Except, pass @pc as null when you want all rows, and use this predicate: "WHERE ( @PC isnull OR Code = @PC ) "

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a multi-step function, you cannot do that an
inline function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetPayCodeList
(     
     -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @PC varchar(50)
)

RETURNS @table TABLE (ID int NOT NULL,
... //others fields ) AS
BEGIN
IF @PC = '*'
INSERT @table (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description
                        FROM   tbl) FROM tbl
ELSE
INSERT @table ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description
                        FROM   tbl
      WHERE Code = @PC) FROM tbl
RETURN @table
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetPayCodeList(          -- Add the parameters for the function here      
@PC varchar(50))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (
    ID int
    , Code varchar(50)
    , Description varchar(max))
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS
BEGIN
IF @PC = '*'      
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description                            
    FROM   tbl      
ELSE             
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Code, Description                            
    FROM   tbl          
    WHERE Code = @PC
END
```

Comment: Warning, making this schema-bound limits your ability to change the underlying tables after the function has been created.

Comment: @Adam: on the other hand *not* marking it schemaboudn will make it perform dismally: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx